# Need Help in WCF-Dependency Injection in WCF

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection

Hi I am planning too create a Broadcasting Service, which will broadcast emergency messages to user. Message can be send through

1. Mail
2. Message
3. SMS

I had created one interface

```
  public interface IBroadCastingMessage
     {
      [OperationContract]
      [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
      bool BroadCastMessage();

       string MessageBody { get; set; }
    }
```

and two classes one for sms and one for mail

```
public class clsSendMail : IBroadCastingMessage
public class clsSendSMS: IBroadCastingMessage
```

and implement broadcast message in both of these two classes.

Now how can I call these methods with the help of DI pattern in WCF,where user will pass the object and in runtime we will decide weather we need to send message through sms or through mail

This is my service but I am getting issue with it,

```
 public class BroadCastingMessage : IserviceInfo
{
  public void IntializeService(IBroadCastingMessage obj)
    {
        obj.BroadCastMessage();
    }
}
```

}

can anyone please let me know right way to achieve this?

Comment: "but I am getting issue with it". Would you like to describe what the issue is?

Comment: you might need a custom service behavior so you can construct the object graph prior to instantiating the service object instance with a proper `IBroadCastingMessage` implementation.

Comment: Steven: I am confused weather this is right way to implement DI? and Second How Client is going to consume this service

Comment: You should use a DI container such as Autofac. http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/wcf.html